How to avoid CORS and iFrame vulnerabilities
I want to make a freemium version of my product, and for that i need to allow third parties to put my website inside an iframe. In order to add some security i added an nginx header to only allow some domains which is
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://random-project.koyeb.app;

If it's deployed to another domain the iframe doesn't load.
The question is, am i being too careless? Is there any other way to secure the api calls for example? Is that content-security-policy the only existing way to enforce security?
I'm using

RubyOnRails in the backend
Next JS in the frontend
Ingress-Nginx as the gateway/app server (K8s)


The frame-ancestors directive has nothing to do with CORS, though.

weirdly enough, it works. I mean, if i don't add that domain, the iframe won't render

I'm not claiming that the frame-ancestors is irrelevant in your use case; only that it's orthogonal to CORS.

I mean, it prevents CORS since doesn't allow iframes to be used. or maybe more like XSS :think:

You seem confused. CORS is only about relaxing the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions on cross-origin network access (HTTP requests/responses). CORS is irrelevant to object access (e.g. from one iframe to another).

Thanks @jub0bs. My concern is that since i'm thinking about putting my cookies to SameSite=none that someone could use the session cookies to hijack the session

Perhaps you're worried about clickjacking, which is a risk if you set your cookies with SameSite=None. But, again, this has nothing to do with CORS.
